# Searching for answerable questions

Tags: support, search

I'm trying to formulate a search query to return the same questions as the "Interesting" tab, except that I also want to filter by "answers <= N". Is there a way to do this?

I'll be mainly looking for questions with ~0 answers. Bonus points for keeping the tag-based highlighting!

Comment: [No need to reinvent the wheel](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=needsanswer)

Comment: @Antony Whaa.. where did that "Recommended" tab come from? Is there a link in the UI for that?

Comment: Why the downvote? I can't find a way to discover that tab from the main UI. It is almost exactly what I wanted..

Comment: There is no UI for that at the moment. See [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1) for details.

Comment: @Antony Well then! Nothing showed up in my pre-question searches or the related questions. I'm glad this feature is in pipeline.

Comment: Have a look at this feature request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270548/stack-overflow-stack-exchange-advanced-search

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following search

> [`[c#] closed:no answers:0..0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0..0)

Or add a score greater than 2:

> [`[c#] score:2 closed:no answers:0..0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+score%3A2+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0..0)

and exclude asp.net

[`[c#] -[asp.net] score:2 closed:no answers:0..0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+-[asp.net]+score%3A2+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0..0)